# Check if bash command has specified modificator

Tags: bash

During the configuration of `Symfony 2` project it is required to set appropriate privilages to the `cache` and `log` directories.

Documentation says to do it in two ways. One of them is calling `setfacl` command with `-m` modificator. However not every version contains this modificator. Is it possible to check if this command or any other command allows to set some modificator ?

For example with following pseudocode:

```
if [ checkmods --command=setfacl --modificator=-m ]
  setfacl -m ....
else
  chmod ...
```

Comment: Just an idea: checking the `$?` for status `0`, since most commands return `1` when executed with an undefined modificator. Although others just ignore them…

Comment: However regular calling command with modificator can affect on the filesystem. I am looking for some sandbox call.

Comment: Do the commands have some `--help` output? Maybe "grepping" for the modificator ; )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the usage information by running `setfacl --help` and check if contains the modificator. For example:

```
if setfacl --help | grep -q -- -m,
then
    echo "setfacl -m supported"
else
    echo "setfacl -m not supported"
fi
```

If you want to do it for any command which has the `--help` option, take a look at the `_parse_help` function available in your bash-completion file.

http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=bash-completion/bash-completion.git;a=blob;f=bash_completion

```
# Parse GNU style help output of the given command.
# @param $1  command; if "-", read from stdin and ignore rest of args
# @param $2  command options (default: --help)
#
_parse_help()
{
    eval local cmd=$( quote "$1" )
    local line
    { case $cmd in
        -) cat ;;
        *) LC_ALL=C "$( dequote "$cmd" )" ${2:---help} 2>&1 ;;
      esac } \
    | while read -r line; do

        [[ $line == *([ $'\t'])-* ]] || continue
        # transform "-f FOO, --foo=FOO" to "-f , --foo=FOO" etc
        while [[ $line =~ \
            ((^|[^-])-[A-Za-z0-9?][[:space:]]+)\[?[A-Z0-9]+\]? ]]; do
            line=${line/"${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"/"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"}
        done
        __parse_options "${line// or /, }"

    done
}
```